# sorting cross tables in sql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, sql-order-by

i have the following query and it is "wrong"

```
    select
        request0_.id as id1_12_,
        request0_.pdf_path as pdf_path2_12_
    from
        request request0_
    cross join
        ptol_user ptoluser1_ 
    where
        request0_.auditor_user_id=ptoluser1_.id 
        and request0_.applicant_user_id=3 
    order by
        ptoluser1_.last_name asc
```

i want to make this query ordered by lastname from the second table but in some rows the varvhar is null and it makes them to disappear these as a result from first condition of where. if it is possbile i want some solutions and into java jpa for spring usage

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help convey what youa re trying to do.  For instance, what is the "varvhar"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include rows where there's no match in the second table, you need to use `LEFT JOIN`, not `CROSS JOIN`.

```
SELECT request0_.id as id1_12_, request0_.pdf_path as pdf_path2_12_
FROM request as request0_
LEFT JOIN ptol_user AS ptoluser1_ ON request0_.auditor_user_id = ptoluser1_.id
WHERE request0_.applicant_user_id = 3
ORDER BY ptoluser1_.last_name ASC
```

Comment: i am using jpa-hibernate and it automatically generates this code.... any idea how to fix it?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know anything about jpa-hibernate.